# How to query EventBridge rules with config/advanced queries?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-event-bridge, aws-config

I'm trying to query EventBridge rules that target a specific lambda across multiple accounts. However, there seem to be no results returned when I run any similar queries:

```
SELECT [...]
WHERE resourceType = 'AWS::Events::Rule'
```

the resources are created through CloudFormation stacks, and they're explicitly created as `AWS::Events::Rule`.

Is there a way to query such rules through aws config advanced queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/query-using-sql-editor-console.html), an updated list of supported resource types, properties and their data types is available in [GitHub](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-config-resource-schema/tree/master/config/properties/resource-types):

[image: Supported resources]

So you can query other resources like `AWS::EC2::Instance`, `AWS::Lambda::Function` or `AWS::S3::Bucket` but `AWS::Events::Rule` is not supported by now.